# Pass php value to bootstrap modal?

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I have a photo list. And when you click on a photo I want to appear a modal with that same photo. So I want php value of photography (foto or id_fotografia) pass to the modal.

the code for the listening of photos is:

```
 <?php
 $query=mysqli_query($db,"select id_fotografia, foto, id_album from fotografias order by id_fotografia DESC limit 10");
 while($cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="portfolio-item">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $cat['id_fotografia']; ?>">
             <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="<?php echo $cat['foto']; ?>"> 
         </a>
       </div>
     </div>
<?php } ?>
```

The code for the modal is:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-body">
            <img src="//want the same photo appears here" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `a` tag to.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-img="<?php echo $cat['foto']; ?>">
```

You need to add some javascript.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var img = button.data('img');
  var modal = $(this);
  modal.find('img').attr('src', img);
})
```